# How to scroll a <object> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a simple web-page to use as an info-screen. I would like it to load two external websites into one page. So far I've succeeded using jquery and the html object-tag:

```
$('#news').html('<object data="http://www.news.com"/>');
$('#weather').html('<object data="http://www.weather.com"/>');
```

Additionally I'd like the object-tags to scroll to a specific position automatically after they've finished loading.
I tried to use the .scrollTop function of jquery but no luck:

```
$('div#news > object').scrollTop(300);
$('div#weather > object').scrollTop(300);
```

I guessed it's because the content of the object tag is not yet loaded when the function is called so I tried to delay it by using

```
sleep(10000);
```

but no luck either.

How can I do this?

Thx a lot in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

```
$('div#news > object').load(function() {

});
```

Comment: Hi meni181818
Thx for you answer. I now tried the following:

`$('div#news > object').load(function() {
 $('div#news > object').scrollTop(300); 
});

$('div#weather > object').load(function() {
 $('div#weather > object').scrollTop(300);   
});`

But it's not working either. Is it possible that the object tag is simply not supported by this scrollTop() function?

Comment: Can anybody please help me on this? It's not a complex thing, there has to be some simple solution I miss! Thx!

Comment: I think for security reasons Web browsers prevent access to embedded objects (`<iframe>`, `<object>`).